# Dynamic CSS to anchor tag

Tags: jquery, css

I am having below html added to example.com site(Very important note).Now I am trying to add CSS to selected link so that I can highlight the value selected.

```
<a class="value" href="http://example.com?filter=value1">Value1
<a class="value" href="http://example.com?filter=value2">Value2 etc
```

Basically I want to apply CSS to the selected anchor tag after it loads the exmaple.com?filter=value1 is loaded.

NOTE: .value:selected{color:blue} doesn't work as the link refreshes the page.

Comment: You can't do this in CSS alone. You would need to write some code which retrieves the current URL and then sets the appropriate class on the `a` element. This can be done either client or server side, but doing it on the server would prevent a FOUC

Comment: About your note: do you want to disable the link to the current page?

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what you want highlight, but you can use this code to see if the URL contains the string you want, and add the desired element CSS code.

```
if(document.location.href.match(/\?filter=value1/)){
   \\Add custom css to element
}
```

For example, this code will add color to the link, only if the user reaches the page through this link:

```
if(document.location.href.match(/\?filter=value1/)){
       $('a[href="http://example.com?filter=value1"]').css('color', 'blue');
}
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".